# Excel / VBA Dynamic Numbers and Text Separation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a value I take from the internet, specifically the market cap of some cryptocurriencies. I get these from the "get external data" function in excel. This loads the data in text format e.g. for a 1000 bitcoin value instead of getting 1000 i will get a cell that had 1000 BTC. Therefore, I am not able to use that data further. If I use the functions right, left, given that this value can fluctuate from 1000 to 1 or 1000000 the right and left will result in text format once the barrier is hit. On the other hand i cannot use the text to column separator as every time i refresh the table goes back to its original state and gets rid of any columns added by the user. Any suggestions to extrapolate the numbers from each cell dynamically are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `Val` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx).

Assuming the cell containing the value you are after is A1 of the active sheet, you can use:

```
Dim numericPart As Double
numericPart = Val(Range("A1").Value)
```

---

If you wanted an Excel formula instead, and there is always a space between the value and the text part, you could use:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another worksheet function, which will work without a space separating the digits from the letters (so long as the digits come first):

```
=LOOKUP(9E+307,--MID(B9,1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

If there might be more than 10 places in the number, merely extend the array constant.

Comment: What if the digits come later? how would you modify that?

Comment: @Nikos Use FIND to locate first digit instead of using `1` for the start.

Answer (score 0):

While getting the external data from the internet, the data may have leading or trailing spaces or non printable leading or trailing characters.

In that case the safest way is to use regular expression to get the numeric part from the string.

Place the following UDF (User Defined Function) on a Standard Module and then use this UDF on the worksheet like below...

Assuming " 1000 BTC " is in A2, then try the UDF like this..

```
=GetNumber(A2)
```

**UDF:**

```
Function GetNumber(rng As Range) As Long
Dim Num As Long
Dim RE As Object, Match As Object, Matches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "\d+"
End With
If RE.test(rng.Value) Then
   Set Matches = RE.Execute(rng.Value)
   GetNumber = Matches(0)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: this is good thanks. But what happens when the number is 1,000. The code above will only return 1

Comment: You only need to change one line in that case Set Matches = RE.Execute(Replace(rng.Value, ",", ""))